# Error "Consulta de Actualizacion" en Access

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2017, ms-access

Tengo un proyecto en VB.Net, en el cual uso una base de datos Access 2016 con una sola tabla. Tengo un formulario sencillo para ingresos de datos, al ejecutarlo desde el Visual Studio funciona perfectamente, al ejecutarlo desde el archivo .exe generado por el proyecto Visual Studio en la carpeta bin/Debug funciona perfectamente,incluso en cualquier computador. Pero no funciona al crear el ejecutable y correrlo desde alli, ni siquiera en la misma computadora donde fue creado el proyecto. En ese caso me da el famoso error "La operacion debe usar una consulta de actualizacion"... He buscado por muchos foros, blogs, webs y ninguna de las sugerencias me ha servido. Si alguien tiene una idea, se lo agradezco. Saludos.

Debo acotar que el ingreso de datos se esta haciendo con una simle consulta "Insert into Tabla (c1,c2,c3) values (v1,v2,v3)". Nada del otro mundo. 
No se si en algun momento debo darle permisos a la tabla para su modificacion o algo parecido.

Comment: Las afirmaciones que haces parecen contradictorias: "en la carpeta bin/Debug funciona perfectamente,incluso en cualquier computador. Pero no funciona al crear el ejecutable y correrlo desde alli, ni siquiera en la misma computadora donde fue creado el proyecto". ¿Qué significa crear el ejecutable? Si ya lo tenías creado en bin/Debug?
Por otro lado, el error más común es que el path de la base de datos sea incorrecto. ¿Te has cercionado que ese no sea el problema?

Comment: Roger te comento, no quise decir crear el ejecutable sinø a hacer el proyecto instalador... Graciad